# htmlWebPack plugin publicPath not working as expected

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-splitchunks

My webpack output:

```
output: {
    publicPath: path.join(basename, '/assets/'),
    path: `${__dirname}/built/core/assets/`,
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
},
```

index.html template:

```html
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script charset="utf-8" src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

Now the problem is when the publicPath is set to `path.join(basename, '/assets')`, then index.html is resolved to:

```html
<script charset="utf-8" src="\assets/bundle.d121bf175aece5f14af6.js"></script>
```

which is ok, however because i haven't added trailing slash to public path, in bundle.[hash].js file, chunks

```js
script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + "." + {"0":"24692a7f9ff51c72880c...
...
__webpack_require__.p = "\\assets";
```

are resolved to `assets[id].[hash].js` without slash and they're not found. However if i add trailing comma to publicPath(`path.join(basename, '/assets/')`) then the index.html is resolved to

```html
<script charset="utf-8" src="\assets\/bundle.d121bf175aece5f14af6.js"></script>
```

and bundle.[hash].js file is not found then.

What am i missing in config?

Comment: have you tried using resolve rather than join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows environment path.join(basename, '/assets/') -> '\assets'

html-webpack-plugin would then check if there's an forward slash at then
end of publicPath and if theres was none it would add it which in turn
would resolve to bundle path being `src="\assets\\/bundle.[hash].js".master`

The application was working in test / prod environments because on unix / macos environments, `path.join(basename, '/assets/')` -> `'/assets/'`.

Added check to webpack config which in turn fixed the problem:

```js
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isDevelopment = environment === 'development';
...
output: {
    publicPath: isDevelopment ? '/assets/' : path.join(basename, '/assets/'),
}
```